# Array of vectors using Thrust

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia, thrust

Is it possible to create an array of device_vectors using Thrust? I know I can't create a device_vector of a device_vector, but how I would create an array of device_vectors?

Comment: While you can do that in Thrust, it is not advisable.  Thrust is only optimized for 1-D vectors.  There are other better libraries for 2 or more dimensional data, e.g. OpenCV GPU, ArrayFire, etc.

Comment: I'll have a look to OpenCV GPU. ArrayFire isn't free for more than one GPU.

Comment: Sounds good.  OpenCV GPU (like Thrust) is significantly slower than ArrayFire, so that is the tradeoff you have to make.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do?  If you want a 2D array, then ArrayFire might be a better bet.  If you just want a host-side array of device_vectors to use in your host code for some other reason, then that is trivial to do.

Comment: @harrism how would you do host-side array of device_vectors? I think that would work for me. It doesn't really to be a 2D array. Although 2D arrays could be addressed in CUDA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code worked for me. If you place this code to a file with .cu extension it compiles well, but if you place it in a file with .cpp extension it gives compile time assertion failure.

```
thrust::device_vector<float> vectors[3];
//thrust::device_vector<float> *vectors = new thrust::device_vector<float>[3];

vectors[0] = thrust::device_vector<float>(10);
vectors[1] = thrust::device_vector<float>(10);
vectors[2] = thrust::device_vector<float>(10);

printf("Works\n");
```

The assertion failure is like the following

```
1>../for_each.inl(96) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'thrust::detail::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<x>'
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it myself!

Comment: Awesome! I think this question/answer will help lots of people!

Comment: @Manolete, I sometimes forget to use the device oriented Thrust codes in .cu files and get some assertion failures. It might also remind it to me.

Comment: @ phoad: Unfortunately, Thrust cannot be populated within kernels, do you have a work-around for that?

Comment: There are method like copy_if etc. Furthermore you may get the raw pointer from Thrust containers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678995/from-thrustdevice-vector-to-raw-pointer-and-back

Comment: It might be better to ask your questions in a new stackoverflow question, so you may provide more information and get clearer answers ;) AFAIK, Thrust library is capable of performing most of the operations that STL containers, algorithms can do.

Comment: @phoad will it work if the size is unknown ?, that is instead of fixing 10 as the size of each vector we do not specify the size.

Comment: Yes. Size of these vectors are defined at run-time, not compile time. So unknown size should be ok.